# How can i generate url with hyphens from title column in mysql table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a mysql table with two columns: Title and url. The url should be from title, and can be created by removing spaces and all characters including spcial characters, then replacing thme with hypens (-)
For example
If the title column is: Tell us more about your @project"
Then Url column becomes: Tell-us-more-about -your-project

Somebody please tell me an sql statement i can use to do that
I just need help for anyone willing to share the knowledge. Please post in ur proposal so i can try

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? Writing a simple `UPDATE` statement should not be that hard

Answer (score 0):

```
update tb set url=replace( replace(title,' ','-'), '@','-')
```

in your case will do the job but in general you have to braket 
multiple time the internal replace with the new character to be replaced : 
replace( (expr) ,'(special char)','-')

Answer (score -1):

You need php str_replace and strtolower or you use Apache Module mod_rewrite

Comment: Nope, none of these two helps to store the proper data in the database

Comment: Oh, now I under the question when I see the answer from BUcorp